# Why would Leaflet be rendering slower on Cell network than on a LAN network

Tags: leaflet

I have a desktop app that makes use of leaflet (browser embedded in the application).

The html containing the calls to LeafLet has already been downloaded from a local webserver and is running on the browser embedder in the application.

Map layer data is downloaded from the database in the desktop app and converted into GeoJSON, and then passed into the browser. I expect the download of the data to take longer on the Cell network, but when I measure the time it takes once the it's been passed into the browser to be rendered on the map is significantly longer.

```
layer.leafletGeoJ = initLayer(gj);
```

e.g., here are my actual logged times

| Activity | LAN | Cell | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Download Data from DB | 141 ms | 574 ms | This I expect, the cell network will be slower than my LAN |
| Upload GeoJason to Browser (load it into 'gj') | 1 ms | 1 ms | This make sense, it's all on the same laptop |
| Render the data with a "initLayer(gj)" | 706 ms | 3478 ms | THIS confuses me - why does the network impact this time |

Subsequent test runs are consistent with these times

What am I missing here? Is there off PC processing happening here some how? If so, is it possible to turn that off (I know you can run leaflet without internet connectivity, with local only data).

There should be no threading involved or lazy loading involved with the downloading of the data from the database. The conversion to GeoJSON should have taken care of that.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your app, the logical guesses are:  caching differences (the fast one cached more), or there really is downloading taking place when you think it is not.  Try adding logging or other changes to disprove those guesses.  For example, in Chrome I'd open F12, disable caching, and look at the network tab.  Another way to test for downloads might be wireshark or other network snooping.

Comment: thanks for the edit @Tangentially Perpendicular